# How do you customize the title of an RSS feed created by Views RSS?

Tags: 7, views, theming, feeds

I have an RSS feed for each user provided by the Views RSS module. The view uses

> users/$uid/feed

as the display path. The feed is titled "All articles by 34 on example.com". The "34" is the userid being viewed. I want the title to be "All articles by username on example.com". I can't set this to use a variable/data in the views title field, which does change the RSS title.

- I can't use `hook_preprocess_html()` or `_page()`, as these  are not called for feeds
- I don't see a hook in the Views RSS module, but I may have missed something
- I don't want to do this in the theme templates for display, as this feels like the wrong place to put the logic

How do I change this? Is there another `preprocess` function I can use?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how much this will help as its not exactly what you're asking (i think):

I was using views_rss to show comment threads to a [question_answer](http://drupal.org/project/question_answer) module question. But I wanted the question to show up as the 1st time in the RSS feed (as RSS feeds) may only show 1 piece of data by their nature (eg, comments or new posts or blog posts) ...

I didn't muck with the title of the Feed because I saw issues with Firefox Sage vs. Google Reader as what the "title" of the RSS feed is -- so I stuffed the "FAQ question" to the comment thread at the top of the RSS feed ....

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_views_pre_render().
 *
 * For the comment rss feed we want the description to contain something such
 * as "topic #N: topic text". These values are excluded in the view already.
 * The RSS feed supports a description field but cannot have PHP code in it,
 * it's just static text.
 *
 * This is a means to theme the RSS description field for valid RSS feeds. The
 * view enforces that the parent node is published, and that comments are
 * published as well.
 *
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011505/how-can-i-add-a-summary-row-to-a-drupal-view
 */
function MYMODULE_discussion_views_pre_render(&$view) {

  if ($view->name == 'MYVIEW_discussion_comment_rss' &&
        $view->current_display == 'feed_1') {
    # Insert the question as a leading comment for this feed.
    $question = node_load(array('nid' => ARG(3)));
    $qrow = new stdClass();
    $qrow->comments_subject = htmlentities('Question Was:');
    $qrow->comments_comment = htmlentities($question->field_topic_text[0]['value']);
    array_unshift($view->result, $qrow);
  }
}
```

**EDIT: My answer was coded for a D6 site, but the exact same principal applies to D7 (and I think the code as well).**

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to the [answer from @tenken](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/25741/1026) which led me to the answer. After parsing the depth of the views array in his hook, I found where I could set the title:

```
function mymodue_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  if($view->name == 'user_rss' && arg(0) == 'users' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
    $account = user_load(arg(1));
    $view->build_info['title'] = t('All articles by !username on Example.com', array(
      '!username' => $account->name,
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this:

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_views_view_rss().
 */
function module_preprocess_views_view_rss(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['view']->name == 'view_machine_name') {
    $vars['title']       = $new_title;  
  }
}
```