# Running a function before a View executes

Tags: views

I have a carousel built using Views (7.x-3.x) that displays 10 items. In this carousel I would like to place 1 item (inclusive of the 10) that displays Twitter content.

What I would like to do is run the function that uses the Twitter API before the View is built/executed. If it succeeds then the View should display 9 items from it's own query (10 items total.) If it fails, then the View would display 10 items from it's own query.

I have successfully implemented the View and the Twitter function running on the theme layer though in order to have a 'fall back' by altering the number of items displayed I would need to do this before the View is built/executed.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for this?

I believe I am looking at the right function "hook_views_query_alter" but I'm not sure how to set "items_per_page"

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first used hook_views_query_alter(). While the code below does work I needed a solution that was a better fit my entire situation.

```
$view->init_pager();
$view->set_items_per_page(x);
```

The better solution was to call the Twitter API during the hook_views_pre_render() phase. If good data was returned then I appended this data to $views for use later.

```
function mymod_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'carousel') {
    $view->mymod_carousel = array();

    $data = twitter(); // custom function that requests data from Twitter API
    if (!empty($data)) {
        $count = count($view->result); // we need to remove the last node in the views result so we always have the same number of items
        if ($count) {
            unset($view->result[$count-1]);
            $view->mymod_carousel['twitter'] = $data;
        }
    }
}
```

Then during hook_views_post_render() I test for this new data and if it is present then I basically result $output using hook_theme() from the jCarousel module.

```
function mymod_views_post_render(&$view, &$output, &$cache) {
  if ($view->name == 'carousel') {
    $result = $view->result;
    $items = array();
    $count = 0;
    foreach($result as $node) { // loop through the results of the view and add our Twitter data at a specific location
        if ($count == 2) {
            if (!empty($view->mymod_carousel['twitter'])) {
                $data = $view->mymod_carousel['twitter'];
                $items[] = theme('mymod_carousel_twitter', array('data' => $data));
                $count++;
            }
        }
        if (!empty($node)) {
            $items[] = theme('mymod_carousel_item', array('node' => $node));
        }
        $count++;
    }   

    $options = $view->style_options;
    $output = theme('jcarousel', array('items' => $items, 'options' => $options));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in a similiar kind of question I answered here:

[How do you customize the title of an RSS feed created by Views RSS?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/25737/how-do-you-customize-the-title-of-an-rss-feed-created-by-views-rss/25741#comment24565_25741)

I would just set the view size to 10 always. And then use array_unshift() as I did in that reply to "prepend" the new item Object to the front of the view results array, if your Twitter call return its 1 item of content. Or else you just let the original 10 come from Views.

Answer (score 0):

The hook you're looking for is probably [pre_render](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7). There you can execute your function and replace the first row of the view with whatever you want.

Comment: You probably should use the proper hook name: hook_views_pre_render().

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer to your question, but I typically set `items_per_page` in [hook_views_pre_build](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_build/7), like

```
function mymodule_views_pre_build (&$view)
{
    if ($_GET["perpage"]) {
        $perpage = check_plain($_GET["perpage"]);

        if (is_numeric($perpage) && (int) $perpage > 1) {
            $view->pager["use_pager"] = TRUE;
            $view->pager["items_per_page"] = (int) $perpage;
        } else if ($perpage == "all") {
            $view->pager["use_pager"] = FALSE;
            $view->pager["items_per_page"] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

This is from a Drupal 6 Views 2 site, but I am pretty sure this still works with Drupal 7 and Views 3.

Comment: I implemented that hook into my module and included -- 
`$view->pager["items_per_page"] = (int) 2;`

This did not change the display items to 2...

Comment: Are you sure the hook is running?  Views 3 may be different.  You may need to tweak the code a bit.

Comment: if I do a `print_r($view->pager);` immediately after I get `Array ( [items_per_page] => 2 )`. Perhaps it is a D6 vs. D7 thing...